# DataGridView RowEnter fires at all the wrong times

Tags: c#

Is this a bug?
I have built a function which should add a new row to my XML database when a new row is added to the DataGridView.
The trouble is, this function fires A) when the page loads, b) when a new row is added, and c) when the program is stopped.

How can I ensure this only happens when it is supposed too?

Comment: Don't use RowEnter? That's what it is supposed to do. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowenter(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Perhaps use RowsAdded https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowsadded(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: RowsAdded fires too often as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want.

```
protected virtual void OnRowsAdded(
    DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e
)
```

Documentation is here.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.onrowsadded(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=fsharp#code-snippet-1